# Is there a viewer for page-speed insight JSON data

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I have a generated report using pagespeed insights api. is there any site or tool which parses this data and show in a readable format. some thing like [this](https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/viewer/)

Comment: have you found any way to download the lighthouse report in json format?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use the [Lighthouse report viewer](https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/viewer/) you suggested.

You have to extract the `lighthouseResult` object from the JSON result and store it as an separate json file. Then you can drag it into the viewer.